# .htaccess friendly url like facebook

Tags: .htaccess

I have following link:

`http://***.com/page.php?g=TWD`

but I want to change link to this:

```
http://***.com/TWD
```

The problem is What I need to do for another pages like index.php?

Here is my .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ page.php?g=$1 [L]
Options -Indexes
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following should allow you to achieve that.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /page\.php\?g=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^page.php /%2? [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

#Internal rewrite
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /page.php?g=$1 [L]
```

`http://***.com/page.php?g=TWD` would be changed to `http://***.com/TWD`

Comment: thanks for your post, but it doesnt work. its could be because i'm use this in wamp?

Comment: its show me `The requested URL /***.com/TWD was not found on this server.`

Comment: So `site.com/page.php?g=TWD` turns to `site.com/TWD`?

Comment: now, when i go to `http://localhost/***.com/TWD` its send me to `http://localhost/page.php?g=TWD`

Comment: Sorry change the last `[R]` to `[L]` I fixed it in my example.

Comment: now its work, thanks. but when i go to `http://localhost/***.com/index`, its show me the content of page.php

Comment: Hmm...is there many pages like that, that shouldn't show the content of page.php

Comment: now its work! i just add the next code before your internal rewrite comment, the code:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f`

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]`

Comment: yes but without the code `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index`, what its for?

Comment: oops...no clue. Removed. Now people can see what your full solution was :)

Comment: Np, feel free to mark the answer as correct so others can see the solution that you got.